# composer update vs composer update --dev

Tags: php, composer-php

```
composer --version
Composer version 1.4.1 2017-03-10 09:29:45
```

and

```
Composer version 1.4.2 2017-05-17 08:17:52
```

As per the [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update) when you run `composer update` it runs by default `composer update --dev`

```
--dev: Install packages listed in require-dev (this is the default behavior).
```

But in my situation with this composer.json:

```
{
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "require-dev": {
      "vagrantin/wp-nonce": "*"
  },
  "require": {
  }
}
```

If I run `composer update` it's downloading **only** the corresponding package here `vagrantin/wp-nonce`.

But if I run `composer update --dev` it will download **all** the dependencies on which this package (`vagrantin/wp-nonce`) depends on, which is the expected behavior.

What i don't understand in this design is that `composer update --dev` is announced as deprecated.

If someone as any clarification about this behavior it will be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is the combinaison I identified to repro this behavior.

In my brand new composer project I'm setting this `composer.json` file

```
{
 "minimum-stability": "dev",
 "require-dev": {
   "vagrantin/wp-nonce": "^0.1"
 },
 "require": {
 }
}
```

And in the package `vagrantin/wp-nonce` I'm setting this `composer.json`

```
{
 "name": "vagrantin/wp-nonce",
 "description": "Playing and testing Wordpress nonces with phpunit tests",
 "keywords": ["wordpress", "test", "phpunit"],
 "type": "library",
 "license": "GPLv2.0+",
 "authors": [
 {
  "name": "Vagrantin",
  "homepage": "http://ll.ducorporation.com"
 }
],
"require": {
    "cyruscollier/wordpress-develop" : "*"
},
"require-dev": {
},
"autoload": {
"classmap": [
  "src"
]
}
```

}

With this setup if i run `composer update` I download *only* "wp-nonce" package.
But if i run `composer update --dev` I download "wp-nonce" package **and all** dependencies.

Also in the `composer.json` of `vagrantin/wp-nonce`, if I'm setting `cyruscollier/wordpress-develop` in `require-dev` instead of `require`. I'm downloading **only** "wp-nonce" either with `composer update` or `composer update --dev`.

would appreciate if someone which as a good understanding of composer could tell me if it's a normal behavior or not.

Thanks !

Comment: so to clarify, with both commands you get the same thing, right?

Comment: no with `composer update --dev` it downloads all the dependencies where `composer update` doesn't. 
updating my post for better clarity.

Comment: thanks, now is clear what you mean. If you try `composer update vagrantin/*` does it change something? Or maybe you have to run it like this: `composer update --with-dependencies`

Comment: If i run `composer update vagrantin/*` i'm getting the same behavior composer install **only** the `wp-nonce` package.

Comment: hmm seems that the documentation is not accurate if this is happening

Comment: Effectively, also I can't find any bug related to this behavior… will see if someone as a better understanding about it otherwise i'll raise an issue on composer github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything defined in `require-dev` is always what you need to provide new functionality in the current library.

Then if you depend, on another library, this library need only to correctly working what is in `require`, but without `require-dev`.

Then login with this, you don't need part of `require-dev` from dependent libraries, for your own development. The flag itself `update --dev` will load everything.

With scenario:

> Also in the composer.json of vagrantin/wp-nonce, if I'm setting cyruscollier/wordpress-develop in require-dev instead of require. I'm downloading only "wp-nonce" either with composer update or composer update --dev.

I think everything is correct.

With the second scenario, where you mark `vagrantin/wp-nonce` as `require-dev`, and in inside `vagrantin/wp-nonce` you `cyruscollier/wordpress-develop`  as `require` - then, in my opinion, this should resolve in download both, with standard calling `composer update`.

Call additional steps

- check update on [packagist](https://packagist.org) if your repositories are correctly loaded or other services you use.
- run `composer self-update`

I think this all should clear the problem.

Comment: Super thanks for the clarification ! accepted answer !